# How to create different template designs for different pages in WordPress

Tags: pages, page-template

OK please see this site.
**ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_58991**

Now check the pages under SERVICES and the pages under OUR STAFF.

This page https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_58991/services/haircuts/ has a different layout than this page
https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_58991/our-staff/alicia-peace/

So how can I achieve that? I am thinking to make the theme like a template to be sold in a marketplace.

Thank you.

Edit: 1) Is it possible to design the page layouts without any page builder? I would like to do it without a page builder.

2) Also what is the best and easiest way to style those pages?

Comment: Hello @user115722 - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! We ask that questions are comprised of a clear problem and question, and additionally demonstrate research and implementation effort on the part of the asker. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more information. What you ask *is* possible without a page builder. Start by [reading up on theme development](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) and try your hand at it - feel free to come back and post another question if you run into specific issues you can't resolve on your own =]

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom [body class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class#Examples) to each page template which you can name according to the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page).

You can add the body class directly to each template file.